# In an equilibrium, why are partial pressures not affected by the coefficients of the balanced equation?

Tags: equilibrium

It's probably easiest for me to explain in an example. For the following reaction: $$\ce{2NOBr(g) <=> 2NO(g) + Br2(g)}$$
At equilibrium, if the partial pressure of $\ce{NOBr}$ was 6 atm, the partial pressure of $\ce{NO}$ was 4 atm, and the partial pressure of $\ce{Br2}$ was 3 atm. Why is the equilibrium constant: $$Kp = \frac{3\cdot 4^2}{6^2}$$ instead of the individual pressures multiplied by their coefficients like in molar solubility: $$Kp = \frac{3\cdot \left(2\cdot 4\right)^2}{\left(2\cdot 6\right)^2}$$

Comment: And your reasoning behind the latter way is .. ?

Comment: @Poutnik Like how solving for molar solubility of Ag2CO3 would give Ksp = (2x)^2 * x

Comment: But the 2 in () is there not because of coefficient itself, but because there is twice as big equilibrium concentration because of that coefficient, assuming all comes from Ag2CO3 dissolution.  If concentrations are general, with external ion source, coefficients play no role in (), just in the exponent.

Answer (score 0):

One way of thinking about this is writing the original equation

$$\ce{2NOBr(g) <=> 2NO(g) + Br2(g)}$$

as

$$\ce{NOBr(g) + NOBr(g)  <=> NO(g) +NO(g) +  Br2(g)}$$

Now it should be clear you have to multiply, not add concentrations.